# How to control mod_autoindex header to insert <meta> tags?

Tags: apache, meta, mod-autoindex

My web server used `mod_autoindex` to give access to a directory of downloadable files.

How can I make the generated html include my own  tags in the header section?

P.S. What I really want is to insert a *viewport* <meta> tag to help prevent Google flagging the website as "not mobile friendly"

Answer (score 4):

The trick is to use the [`IndexHeadInsert`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_autoindex.html#indexheadinsert) directive in your mod_autoindex config. For me, using Arch Linux, that's in `/etc/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf` but it may be different on your distro.

```
IndexOptions FancyIndexing HTMLTable VersionSort
IndexHeadInsert "<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\">"
```

Comment: Also works in .htaccess.